# Add Focus to TextView in Popover

Tags: ios, swift

I'll try to add the focus on a TextView inside a Popover, but I wont work at the moment. It should get the focus direct after load.

I use:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.textView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

But nothing happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a confusion between `-becomeFirstResponder` and `-resignFirstResponder`. Your code has to be:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.textView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```